# Merge two matrices into a max matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, max

Lets say I have

```
a = [2, 5; 1, 1];
b = [3, 3; 0.5, 9];
```

I want to get this matrix in result

```
maxMat = [3, 5; 1, 9];
```

I could do this using loops

```
[x, y] = size(a);
for i=1:x
   for j=1:y
       maxMat(i, j) = max(a(i,j), b(i,j));
   end
end
```

Is there a faster way ? and a much cleaner code without using loops ?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [2, 5; 1, 1];
b = [3, 3; 0.5, 9];

c = bsxfun(@max,a,b)

% c =
%      3     5
%      1     9
```

For details, see [the language reference for bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); element by element binary operation.

Comment: `bsxfun` is generally very useful, but you don't need it when the two arrays have the same size

Comment: @LuisMendo You're right, I went straight for the somewhat bigger guns. Thanks for you feedback!

Answer (score 8):

It's as simple as

```
maxMat = max(a,b);
```

The [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function with two inputs computes the maximum of corresponding entries.